# how to make a single slide with markdown and code in ipython notebook?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

In this tutorial presentation they use this, but, apparently, they don't show you how to do it.

http://www.damian.oquanta.info/posts/make-your-slides-with-ipython.html

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry, I completely misunderstood your question.

If you mean embedding code which you do not execute, then you can use simple markdown syntax (similar to StackOverflow for example). To include inline code, just but it between backticks:

```
 For example `a[::2]` selects every second element of the list `a`.
```

If you want to include a code block, either indent the whole block by 4 spaces, or put the block between 3 backticks (the latter also supports syntax highlighting if you specify the language):

```
    a = foo()
    b = bar(a)
```

or

````
```python
a = foo()
b = foo(a) 
```
````

For more, see [this markdown tutorial](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#code).

If you want to include executable cells and markdown on the same slide, then you need to put your code and markdown into different cells, and for slide type select `slide` for the topmost cell, and `-` for the subsequent cells that you want to have on the same slide. `-` means "do not start a new slide for this cell".

#### Old answer (how to convert a notebook to a reveal.js presentation)

You can convert your ipython notebook to a Reveal.js presentation using nbconvert.

First you have to specify the structure of the presentation. For that click on `View -> Cell Toolbar -> Slideshow`. Then at the top of every cell you can select whether you want it to be a new slide (horizontal direction), a subslide (vertical direction), a fragment (appear on the same slide with a fade-in) and some others.

Once you are set, you can use the `nbconvert` utility to transform your notebook into a presentation. The basic usage is

```
jupyter nbconvert example.ipynb --to slides
```

Then you get a HTML which you can serve up later using some web server.

If you want to show off your slides right away, jupyter provides a shortcut: you can do

```
jupyter nbconvert example.ipynb --to slides --post serve
```

Using this jupyter starts a local server after the conversion and opens the presentation in your default browser.

Last, if you want to easily share your presentation online, you can upload the notebook to some online repository (for example to github as a gist), and you can use [nbviewer](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/) to share it. It will have a box-like icon in the top right corner. If you press it, it will change from notebook mode to presentation mode (I don't understand the box analogy either).

For more info please consult the [jupyter documentation](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/notebook/nbconvert.html).